# opencv grabcut saving the result

Tags: c++, opencv, io, saving-data

in the standard grabcut program that comes in the samples of opencv, I added a few lines of code to save the result to a file. However, nothing is there in the file. Just a black solid color. Here's the code that I put in --

in the main function

```
case 's':
    gcapp.writeToFile(writefilename);
    break;
```

in the GCApplication class

```
void writeToFile(string filename)
{
    imwrite(filename, mask);
    cout << "file written" << endl;
}
```

I'm assuming that you know the grabcut program and you have the code to look at it. Please let me know if I need to post more info... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are saving the wrong `cv::Mat`.** The one that is displayed at the end of `showImage()` is `res`, which is a local variable. You should make it a class variable, and then the method `writeToFile()` should execute:

```
imwrite(filename, res);
```